# CakePHP saveMany doesnt save

Tags: cakephp-2.5, cakephp

I have the following Form Code.

```
<?php echo $this
   ->Form
   ->create(
       'PagePhoto',
       array(
           'type' => 'file',
           'url' => array(
                'controller' => 'page_photos',
                'action' => 'add'
            )
       )
  ); ?>
  <div class="modal-body has-padding">
       <div class="form-group">
       <?php echo $this->Form->label('PagePhoto.0.filename', 'Photos:'); ?>
       <br/><br/>
       <?php echo $this->Form->file('PagePhoto.0.filename', array('required' => false)); ?>
       <?php echo $this->Form->error('PagePhoto.0.filename', null, array('class' => 'label label-block label-danger text-left', 'wrap' => 'label')); ?>
       <br/>
       <?php echo $this->Form->file('PagePhoto.1.filename', array('required' => false)); ?>
       <?php echo $this->Form->error('PagePhoto.1.filename', null, array('class' => 'label label-block label-danger text-left', 'wrap' => 'label')); ?>
       <br/>
       <?php echo $this->Form->file('PagePhoto.2.filename', array('required' => false)); ?>
       <?php echo $this->Form->error('PagePhoto.2.filename', null, array('class' => 'label label-block label-danger text-left', 'wrap' => 'label')); ?>
       <br/>
       <?php echo $this->Form->file('PagePhoto.3.filename', array('required' => false)); ?>
       <?php echo $this->Form->error('PagePhoto.3.filename', null, array('class' => 'label label-block label-danger text-left', 'wrap' => 'label')); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Photos</button>
</div>
```

Which returns the following array to the `add` action

```
array(
    'PagePhoto' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'filename' => array(
                'name' => 'IMG_1683.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'tmp_name' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpoIrbZ6',
                'error' => (int) 0,
                'size' => (int) 94131
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'filename' => array(
                'name' => 'IMG_1683.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'tmp_name' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpAcbXbC',
                'error' => (int) 0,
                'size' => (int) 94131
            )
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'filename' => array(
                'name' => 'IMG_1683.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'tmp_name' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phppCeN8G',
                'error' => (int) 0,
                'size' => (int) 94131
            )
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'filename' => array(
                'name' => 'IMG_1683.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'tmp_name' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php8Ib3bO',
                'error' => (int) 0,
                'size' => (int) 94131
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Add Action**

```
public function admin_add() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            debug($this->request->data);
            $this->PagePhoto->create();
            if ($this->PagePhoto->saveMany($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The gallery has been saved.'), 'admin/flash_success');
                // return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->request->data['Gallery']['album_id']));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The gallery could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'admin/flash_error');
            }
        } else {
            // $this->request->data['Gallery']['album_id'] = $album_id;
        }
    }
```

Error:

> FAILURE: The gallery could not be saved. Please, try again.

Comment: there is nothing with your form data, it seems to be formatted properly. may be check your model validation rules as save operation is halted if  validation error occurs  and cause the saveMany to return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $this->PagePhoto->saveMany($this->request->data['PagePhoto']);
```

Note: When saving multiple records of same model the records arrays should be just numerically indexed without the model key.